# launching emulator to tablet size after building android source code

Tags: android

I am build the code with default instruction given on the source.android.com like

1) source build/envsetup.sh
2) launch full-eng
3) make

When I try to launch the emulator it open in default size of a bar-phone.But I want to launch my emulator in tablet size(any default size is enough).

Comment: Just set your AVD's skin to 'WXGA800' and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tablet skin. You can change skin in AVD manager. 
Found here:
     [SDK]/platforms//skins

Comment: search in my latest downloaded code but I didn't find android source code but I didn't find android folder platforms under sdk folder.

Comment: Make sure you've downloaded an SDK of platform 3.0 upwards. Create an avd with a tablet size skin. Choose an api level for the target and choose one of the XGA skins.

Comment: I already mentioned I have download android source code from source.android.com not only complied sdk. current version of android is 4.0.3

Comment: now in eclipse go to Window>AVD Manager>New...>  name it, target: 4.0.3, skin: WXGA800

Answer (score 0):

```
 emulator -skin <skinname>
```

For list of skins in aosp avaliable - see droid/development/tools/emulator/skins